# Null pointer passed as argument 1

Tags: c, cs50, null-pointer

In line `int d = atoi(argv[2]);` there seems to be something wrong. "null pointer passed as argument 1..."

What can I do?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    int num;
    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;
    int board [i][j];

   // 2nd CL argument is size of grid.

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        return false;
    }

    int d = atoi(argv[2]);

    if (d <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // setting up board.

    // number of tiles needed.
    num = d * d - 1;

    // iterating over columns and rows
    for (i = 0; i <= d; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= d; j++)
        {
            // set values.
            board[i][j] = num;
            num --;
        }
         printf ("%d", board[i][j]); // TESTING.
         printf ("\n");
    }

   // if even swap 1 & 2. Don't display 1.
}
```

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?

Comment: The program enforces 2 arguments, but then tries to check the third argument. Remember that the program invocation itself is counted as one argument and that arrays are zero-indexed.

Comment: `argv[2]` is the _third_ element of `argv[]`; there is no argv[3] when `argc == 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv[0]` holds the name of the command used to start your program. If you expect two command line arguments, check `argc == 3` and read the command line arguments from `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a multiple issues with your program

1) `string` is not a standard type in C.

2) `false` is not a standard constant in C98.

Standard C (since C99) provides a boolean type, called _Bool. By including the header `stdbool.h` one can use the more intuitive name bool and the constants `true` and `false`.

3) Your board has a fixed size 1x1 `board[1][1]`:

```
   int i = 1;
   int j = 1;
   int board [i][j];
```

Fix this otherwise your program will smash memory.

4) You need 2 arguments for your board. Arguments start on position `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` in `argv[]` Since first argv[0] is name of the program you need `argc` = 3.

Comment: `string` is defined in `cs50.h`. `false` is used as a value, not a type (and `_Bool` is in fact a standard type).

Comment: Standard C (since C99) provides a boolean type, called _Bool. By including the header stdbool.h one can use the more intuitive name bool and the constants true and false